# Can, I use cluster with worker threads in nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, node-cluster, node-worker-threads

Is it possible to use cluster + worker thread if I have a use case where I am getting multiple concurrent requests which are CPU-intensive.
Will that do better in performance?

I implemented clusters in my project, where a separate NodeJS instance start, now can each of that instance can spawn multiple worker threads? if yes is it feasible to do so?